# Random Samples from Spliced Distribution

Tags: r, sampling, mixture-distribution, power-law, quantiles

I am studying Clauset, Shalizi, and Newman, Power Law Distributions in Empirical Data (preprint available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062)) in R. Packages used:

```r
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
require(magrittr)
```

The paper defines power law distributions as any distribution such that the density function in the tails, i.e. for values greater than some $x_{min}$, is proportional to $(x/x_{min})^{-\alpha}$. I am trying to replicate their testing of their methodology for estimating the $x_{min}$ parameter. In order to do so, they construct a distribution having the following probability density function:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
       Ce^{-\alpha(x/x_{min}-1)} & x \leq x_{min} \\
       C(x/x_{min})^{-\alpha} & x > x_{min}
       \end{cases}
$$

Thus $X$ is exponentially distributed, and does not scale below $x_{min}$, but does above it. In order to test their methodology, I must draw random samples from this distribution. I was able to reproduce their experiments earlier in the paper using [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Truncated_distribution), but I have not been able to figure out how to do so with this distribution. I have solved for the normalizing constant by setting sum of the integrals of each splice over their support equal to one:

$$
1 = \int_0^{x_{min}}{Ce^{-\alpha(x/x_{min}-1)} dx} + \int_{x_{min}}^\infty{C(x/x_{min})^{-\alpha} dx} \\
C = (e^{-\alpha(1/x_{min}-1)}(e^{x_{min}}-1)+\frac{x_{min}}{\alpha-1})^{-1}
$$

This appears to give a reasonable distribution:

```r
xmin <- 1
alpha <- 1.5
const <- (exp(-alpha * (1/xmin - 1)) * (exp(xmin) - 1) + xmin / (alpha - 1))^-1
data.table(x = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = .1))[
  ,
  y := ifelse(
    x < xmin,
    const * exp(-alpha * (x/xmin - 1)),
    const * (x/xmin)^-alpha
  )
] %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
    theme_bw()
```

But that is as far as I have gotten. Below is my best attempt at a function to draw random variates using inverse transform sampling. It appears to give reasonable results for small $x_{min}$, but is obviously wrong for large $x_{min}$, like the value of 100 they use in the paper:

```r
rexppow <- function(n, xmin, alpha){
  # normalizing constant of spliced distribution
  const <- (exp(-alpha * (1/xmin - 1)) * (exp(xmin) - 1) + xmin / (alpha - 1))^-1
  # probability that x < xmin
  cutoff <- const * exp(-alpha * (1/xmin - 1)) * (exp(xmin) - 1)
  # for specified number of draws...
  if(length(n) > 1) n <- length(n)
  ret <- numeric(n)
  for(i in seq_len(n)){
    # ...draw from U(0, 1) to determine which portion of
    # distribution to sample...
    # ...and perform inverse transform sampling on specified portion
    # of spliced distribution
    if(runif(1) < cutoff){
      draw <- Inf
      while(draw >= xmin){
        draw <- log1p(runif(1) / (const * exp(-alpha * (1/xmin - 1))))
      }
      ret[i] <- draw
    } else {
      draw <- 0
      while(draw < xmin){
        draw <- (xmin^-alpha
                 * ((1 - alpha)
                   * (runif(1) / const - (exp(-alpha * (1 / xmin - 1))
                                          * (exp(xmin)-1)
                                          )
                      )
                   + xmin
                   )
                 )^(1 / (1 - alpha))
      }
      ret[i] <- draw
    }
  }
  return(ret)
}

set.seed(1)
hist(rexppow(1000, 100, 1.5), breaks = 1000)
```

Here are the equations written nicely (I'm not sure how to make them look better in code):

$$
Pr(X \leq x_{min}) = \int_0^{x_{min}}{Ce^{-\alpha(x/x_{min}-1)} dx} \\
= Ce^{-\alpha(1/x_{min} - 1)}(e^{x_{min}}-1) \\
u_{x \leq x_{min}} = F(F^{-1}(u))_{x \leq x_{min}} = \int_0^{F^{-1}(u)}{Ce^{-\alpha(x/x_{min}-1)} dx} \\
= ln \left( 1 + u / (Ce^{-\alpha * (1/x_{min} - 1)}) \right) \\
u_{x > x_{min}} = F(F^{-1}(u))_{x > x_{min}} = Pr(X \leq x_{min}) + \int_{x_{min}}^{F^{-1}(u)}{C(x/x_{min})^{-\alpha} dx} \\
= \left( x_{min}^{-\alpha}((1 - \alpha)(u/C - e^{-\alpha(1/x_{min} - 1)}(e^{x_{min}} - 1)) + x_{min}) \right)^{\frac{1}{1 - \alpha}}
$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It's simpler to think of this as a mixture distribution.  One samples from mixtures by first selecting a component randomly and then drawing from that component.  In the present case these procedures are easily carried out without any further calculation.

Comment: @whuber So 1) the line `if(runif(1) < cutoff)` should be `if(runif(1) < .5)` and the inverse CDFs of each function separately, rather than together, should be used, i.e. $F(F{-1}(u))$ should not include the term $Pr(X \leq x_{min})$?

Comment: I don't see where the `.5` comes from. In `R` pseudocode you can sample from a mixture of two distributions with weights `p` and `1-p` by writing functions `rF` and `rG` to generate variates for the components and invoking something like `ifelse(runif(n) < p, rF(n), rG(n))` to obtain `n` variates from the mixture.